# Migrate PHP website from Apache to Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php

What are the implications of moving a site build in PHP 7 on a server running Apache 2.2 to another running nginx 1.12 (CentOS)?

Is there any standard practice for doing this? Are there any guidelines?

How do I know what directories should I put my PHP stuff when moving server with Apache to the other with nginx?    What about scripts?  How should I deal with .htacess?

Comment: Are you running PHP as an Apache module or through FastCGI or PHP-FPM? If you are already using PHP-FPM, moving to Nginx should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: through FastCGI